# Simulate "do not disturb" functionality in PHP

Tags: php

I want to check between two user-specified times everyday and not run some function call (i.e. "Do Not Disturb").

For example, a user set a "Do Not Disturb" time block between 10:00pm to 6:00am (next day).

FYI, no days/dates are being specified by the end-user, ONLY times.  This will run consistently everyday, 7 days a week.

So between 10pm-6am (next day), any function call is ignored.  This is what I've written up so far:

```
$now = time(); // or $now = strtotime('11:00pm'); to simulate time to test
$start = strtotime('10:00pm');
$end = strtotime('6:00am +1 day');
// alternative time block
//$start = strtotime('10:00am');
//$end = strtotime('11:00am');

//debug
//echo date('r', $now) . '<br>' . date('r', $start) . '<br>' . date('r', $end) . '<br><br>';

if($start > $now || $now > $end) {
   echo 'disturb';
} else {
   echo 'do not disturb';
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, because once you reach midnight, it's a new day, but the `$end` variable is already a day ahead.

I tried putting it a day behind, but then the issue is that the value of `$end` ends up being lower than the value of `$start`, which isn't correct.

I also tried adding a day to the `$now` variable whenever the time reaches midnight, but the issue w/ that is, what if the `$start` and `$end` times are within the same day?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently you're trying to build some kind of calendar functionality here.

If you use `strtotime('10:00pm');` this will change to the timestamp of the next day after midnight.

So you need to give the variable a date

```
 $start = strtotime('2015-02-26 10:00pm');
 $end = strtotime('2015-02-27 6:00am');
```

Not sure how you store these time blocks, but ideally they would be stored in a database table.

If it's every day the same you could do:

```
$now = time(); // or $now = strtotime('11:00pm'); to simulate time to test
$start = strtotime('10:00pm');
$end = strtotime('6:00am'); // without the +1 day

if($start > $end) {
   if($start > $now && $now > $end) { 
      echo 'disturb';
   } else {
      echo 'do not disturb';
   }
}else{
   if($now < $start || $now > $end) { 
      echo 'disturb';
   } else {
      echo 'do not disturb';
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I tested this again and it doesn't quite work 100%.  If you set the `$start` time to be 10:00am, and the `$end` time to be 11:00am for example, this doesn't work.  No matter what time you put for `$now`, it will never reach "disburb"

Comment: Okay I added another if clause in my answer that takes this case also in consideration.

Comment: yeah I eventually came to this conclusion too, an hour before you posted this.  was about to post the answer, but looks like you beat me to it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert to [DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects instead.  Then you won't get any issues with days ending.

```
// obviously you'll need to feed in the date as well so
// that might involve some refactoring

$now = new DateTime();
$start = new DateTime('2015-02-26 10:00');
$end = new DateTime('2015-02-27 06:00');
```

Now you can compare as before.

If you don't know the date and your users are only specifying time, you might need to add the date dynamically.  These are just for example.

Edit: to cope with unknown days, you could dynamically generate after grabbing today:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$start = new DateTime($today->format('Y-m-d') . ' 10:00');
$end = new DateTime($today->format('Y-m-d') . ' 06:00');
$end->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

Comment: There's no set date; this will run everyday, 7 days a week, consistently.  But thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: this doesn't work if you set the `$start` time at 10:00 (10am), and the `$end` time at 11:00 (11am).  It's because you're adding a day to the `$end` variable, which isn't correct.  Sure, you can remove it for that instance, but then at the stroke of midnight, the routine fails.

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice question actually,

You can use the the relatively new object oriented way of dealing with times.

I'll link you some info as I don't have time to write an entire example
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

specifically from the docs :

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Hope it helps